# Liquibase customPrecondition causes maven plugin to fail

Tags: maven, liquibase

We have our liquibase scripts setup in a maven project and we are using the liquibase maven plugin to execute the scripts on deploy of our software.

We need to ensure that only the liquibase scripts relevant to the version of the software being deployed are run.

I have created a custom PreCondition in liquibase for each changeset as follows:

```
<preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
    <customPrecondition className="class.CompatibleVersion">
        <param name="version" value="1.0.0"/>
    </customPrecondition>
</preConditions>
```

This preCondition throws a CustomPreconditionFailedException when the precondition version parameter is > deployedVersion.

The precondition is working unfortunately whenever it throws the CustomPreconditionFailedException instead of skipping the change set (onFail="CONTINUE") the maven plugin fails with the following:

```
Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set src/database/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.1.xml::1.0.1_script1::fred.smith:
[ERROR] Reason:
[ERROR] db.changelog-master.xml : liquibase.precondition.CustomPreconditionWrapper@2add4d24 : liquibase.exception.CustomPreconditionFailedException: Change set version : 1.0.1 incompatible with deploy version : 1.0.0. Skipping change set. Precondition Error
```

This is the exception I expect it to throw but I am expecting the change set to be skipped due to the onFail="CONTINUE".

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of liquibase-maven-plugin do you use? For me it works fine with the newest version 3.5.3.

Comment: We are using 3.5.3 also.  This is within eclipse using a run configuration with the goal process-resources -Denv=test.
env resolves to a property file within the project.

Comment: Solved.  Programming error on my part - the precondition was throwing the wrong exception type.